# Como validar um input?

Tags: javascript, formulário, formulário-submeter

Tenho um formulário que envia os valores inseridos nas `input` para uma outra página. Quero fazer uma validação entre as inputs, caso um número seja maior que outro, e caso não seja, não passar para a segunda página e avisar com um `alert`.

Este é o meu código HTML:

```html
<form action="_graphes.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="time" id="time_debut" name="time_debut" step="1" value=''>
  <input type="time" id="time_fin" name="time_fin" step="1" value='' >
  <input id=btn type=submit name=go value=ok>
</form>
```

E o javascript:

```js
if(document.getElementById("time_debut").value > document.getElementById("time_fin").value){
    alert("Maior");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode validar o formulário seguindo o exemplo abaixo, **complementando coloquei a validação para verificar se um ou os dois campos estão vazios**:

**html**

```
<form action="_graphes.php" method="post" id="formulario"> 
    <input type="time" id="time_debut" name="time_debut" step="1" value="">
    <input type="time" id="time_fin" name="time_fin" step="1" value="" >
    <input id="btn" type="button" onclick="return envia()" name="go" value="ok">
</form>
```

O `input` 'btn' quando é clicado ele chama a função `envia()` abaixo, onde ocorre a validação e envio do `form`.

**js**

```
function envia() {
        var time_debut = document.getElementById("time_debut").value;
        var time_fin = document.getElementById("time_fin").value;
        if(time_debut == '' || time_fin == '') {
            alert("Preencha todos os campos!");
        }
        else if (time_debut > time_fin){
            alert("Maior");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
        }   
    }
```

**js (Sem validar se os campos estão vazios)**

```
function envia() {
            var time_debut = document.getElementById("time_debut").value;
            var time_fin = document.getElementById("time_fin").value;
            if (time_debut > time_fin){
                alert("Maior");
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
            }   
        }
```

Comment: O type do button, tem de ser button, senão com o submit  passa sempre para a proxima pagina.

Comment: @akm mudei para 'button', valeu.

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer colocando o submit apenas no javascript.

Este é o seu HTML:

```html
<form id="frm" action="_graphes.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="time" id="time_debut" name="time_debut" step="1" value=''>
  <input type="time" id="time_fin" name="time_fin" step="1" value='' >
  <input id="btn" type="button" onclick="javascript: btn_click()" name="go" value="ok">
</form>
```

E o javascript:

```js
function btn_click() {
    if (document.getElementById("time_debut").value > document.getElementById("time_fin").value) {
        alert("Maior");
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("frm").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Na tag `form`, acrescente uma chamada à função de validação do formulário.

```
<form action="_graphes.php" method="post" onsubmit="validar()">
```

A função de validação vai conter o trecho de código que você já construiu:

```
function validar() {
    if(document.getElementById("time_debut").value > document.getElementById("time_fin").value) {
        alert("Maior");
        return (false);
    }
    else {
        return (true);
    }
}
```

O `return(false)` vai fazer com que a submissão do formulário seja interrompida, e a próxima página não seja chamada.